# ValueError: Can't handle mix of multilabel-indicator and binary Issue with GridSearchCV and KerasClassifier

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, mnist

I have this CNN code for the MNIST data that divides the dataset into training set and test set for only 2's and 7's. On running it the code it gives about 98% Accuracy on the test set.

So, to increase the Accuracy I tried using KerasClassifier from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn. Using the Classifier with GridSearchCV I was thinking to find the optimal parameters but on running the code 1st Iteration goes all fine but throws an error from the next Iteration.

Here is the code:

```
# This is the normal CNN model without GridSearch
from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np
batch_size = 128
num_classes = 2
epochs = 12
# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

# the data, shuffled and split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

#Only look at 3s and 8s
train_picks = np.logical_or(y_train==2,y_train==7)
test_picks = np.logical_or(y_test==2,y_test==7)

x_train = x_train[train_picks]
x_test = x_test[test_picks]
y_train = np.array(y_train[train_picks]==7,dtype=int)
y_test = np.array(y_test[test_picks]==7,dtype=int)


if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(4, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])

# Improving the accuracy using GridSearch
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
def build_model(optimizer):
    print(optimizer,batch_size,epochs)
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(4, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                  optimizer=optimizer,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn = build_model)
parameters = {'batch_size': [128, 256],
              'epochs': [10, 20],
              'optimizer': ['rmsprop']}
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = model,
                           param_grid = parameters,
                           scoring = 'accuracy',
                           cv = 10)
grid_search = grid_search.fit(x_train, y_train)
best_parameters = grid_search.best_params_
best_accuracy = grid_search.best_score_
```

This is the Output of the code:

```
rmsprop 128 12
Epoch 1/10
11000/11000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.1654 - acc: 0.9476      
Epoch 2/10
11000/11000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.0699 - acc: 0.9786     
Epoch 3/10
11000/11000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.0557 - acc: 0.9839     
Epoch 4/10
11000/11000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.0510 - acc: 0.9839     
Epoch 5/10
11000/11000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.0471 - acc: 0.9853     
Epoch 6/10
11000/11000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.0417 - acc: 0.9875     
Epoch 7/10
11000/11000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.0399 - acc: 0.9870     
Epoch 8/10
11000/11000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.0365 - acc: 0.9885     
Epoch 9/10
11000/11000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.0342 - acc: 0.9899     
Epoch 10/10
11000/11000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.0321 - acc: 0.9903     
 768/1223 [=================>............] - ETA: 0sTraceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-975b20661114>", line 30, in <module>
    grid_search = grid_search.fit(x_train, y_train)

  File "/home/thakkar_/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 945, in fit
    return self._fit(X, y, groups, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))

  File "/home/thakkar_/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 564, in _fit
    for parameters in parameter_iterable

  File "/home/thakkar_/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 758, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):

  File "/home/thakkar_/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 608, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)

  File "/home/thakkar_/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 571, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)

  File "/home/thakkar_/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 109, in apply_async
    result = ImmediateResult(func)

  File "/home/thakkar_/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 326, in __init__
    self.results = batch()

  File "/home/thakkar_/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 131, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]

  File "/home/thakkar_/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 131, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]

  File "/home/thakkar_/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 260, in _fit_and_score
    test_score = _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)

  File "/home/thakkar_/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 288, in _score
    score = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)

  File "/home/thakkar_/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py", line 98, in __call__
    **self._kwargs)

  File "/home/thakkar_/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py", line 172, in accuracy_score
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)

  File "/home/thakkar_/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py", line 82, in _check_targets
    "".format(type_true, type_pred))

ValueError: Can't handle mix of multilabel-indicator and binary
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seem to be in the way you parsing the dictionary parameters..

An example from [here](http://machinelearningmastery.com/grid-search-hyperparameters-deep-learning-models-python-keras/):

```
import numpy
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from keras.optimizers import SGD
# Function to create model, required for KerasClassifier
def create_model(learn_rate=0.01, momentum=0):
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    optimizer = SGD(lr=learn_rate, momentum=momentum)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)
# load dataset
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("pima-indians-diabetes.csv", delimiter=",")
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:8]
Y = dataset[:,8]
# create model
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=100, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
# define the grid search parameters
learn_rate = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
momentum = [0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9]
param_grid = dict(learn_rate=learn_rate, momentum=momentum)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1)
grid_result = grid.fit(X, Y)
# summarize results
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))
```

GridseachCV basically takes elements from the dictionary that matches with its input parameter, and train it.  You are parsing the complete dictionary, but `batch_size`, and `epochs` aren't parameter within the function...

```
# Improving the accuracy using GridSearch
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
def build_model(optimizer = 'adam'):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(4, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                  optimizer=optimizer,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn = build_model)
parameters = {'batch_size': [128, 256],
              'epochs': [10, 20],
              'optimizer': ['rmsprop']}
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = model,
                           param_grid = parameters,
                           scoring = 'accuracy',
                           cv = 10)
grid_search = grid_search.fit(x_train, y_train)
best_parameters = grid_search.best_params_
best_accuracy = grid_search.best_score_
```

Maybe something like this would work.. have not tested it.

Comment: No @J.Down the batch_size and epochs were there to print. Their presence matters only in the param_grid. The problem is somewhere with the y_test and y_train.

Comment: @DhavalThakkar Yes. thats right. Can you please check the format of your `y_train` that you pass in GridSearchCV and the output of `KerasClassifier.predict(X_train)`?